# Interact with remote geth node with metamask using SSH

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, rpc

I have a geth node running on a server. There are no ports open on the server, the only access is using SSH tunnel. I want to interact with the node using metamask extension. Is there any way to do so using SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to connect through ssh then the ssh port is open. As such, try by connecting directing to the port through metamask.

Another option would be to connect and open the browser remotely using X11 with the -X when ssh-ing. This option requires more connection power.

Finally, try doing ssh tunneling from the local browser through the ssh port, though I think won't work.